# Style link based on page url with jquery, doesn't work with "www."

Tags: jquery

I'm using this bit of jquery to style the links on my site based on the page url:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var url =window.location;
$("#left a").each(function() {
   if($(this).attr('href') == url){
      $(this).addClass('current');
   }
});
        });
```

And the html for each link is like this:

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/our-company.html">Our Company</a>
```

the problem is if someone tries to go to www.mysite.com/our-company.html, the styling won't work.

How can I remove the "www." from the variable?  I tried putting a ".replace" in several different spots but I'm a newbie.

I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var urla = window.location;
var urlb = urla.replace("www.","");

$("#left a").each(function() {
  if($(this).attr('href') == urlb){
   $(this).addClass('current');
 }
});
        });
```

which just tries to redirect to "http://mysite.com/www."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the href of the url, not the url itself.
Using `window.location.href`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // `.href` added
    var urla = window.location.href;
    var urlb = urla.replace("www.","");

    $("#left a").each(function() {
        if($(this).attr('href') == urlb){
            $(this).addClass('current');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Isn't the second part redundant though since 'urlb' will return the same value if there isn't a "www." to replace?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 var url = windown.location;
 var url2 = url.replace("www.", "");

$("#left a").each(function() {
  if($(this).attr('href') == url2){
   $(this).addClass('current');
 }
```

});
        })

Comment: That I actually already tried, it just tries to go to 'www.mysite.com/www.'

Comment: @Jared, did you set the order of the parameters correctly? first is what you want to replace, second is the what to replace with

Comment: Yeah I, updated my question with what I tried which was pretty much exactly what Machinegon suggested